# PHP - Split an array into chunks.

Tags: php, html, css

I have a variable on my page called,     `$recipe['ingredients'];`

inside the var you have as follows,

100ml milk, 350ml double cream, 150ml water

and so on.  Now I'm trying to split it up so it looks as follows

```
<ul>
    <li>100ml milk</li>
    <li>350ml double cream</li>
    <li>150ml water</li>
</ul>
```

So far I have the following code,

```
$ingredientsParts = explode(',', $row_rs_recipes['ingredients']);
$ingredients = array($ingredientsParts);
while (! $ingredients) { 
   echo" <li>$ingredients</li>";
}
```

But for some reason it doesn't work and I do not have the experience with explode to fix it.

Comment: PHP's `explode()` returns an array: http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Comment: `$ingredients = array($ingredientsParts);`
You don't need this. `ingredientsParts` is already an array after explosion.

I would, personally, use `for` or `foreach` loop to traverse whole array but that's up to you. I'm not sure if it could be done by this `while` condition. Are you trying to reference to array internal pointer by `!$ingredients`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. When you explode() a string it is automatically converted into an array. You do not need to convert it to an array type as you did on the second line.
2. You want to use a foreach() loop to iterate through an array, not a while loop.

   ```
      $ingredientsAry = explode(',', $row_rs_recipes['ingredients']);
      foreach($ingredientsAry as $ingredient){
          echo "<li>$ingredient</li>";
      }
   ```

In fact you can just do a foreach() loop on the explode() value

```
foreach(explode(',', $row_rs_recipes['ingredients']) as $ingredient){
    echo "<li>$ingredient</li>";
}
```

Comment: you forgot the space after a comma

Comment: @bzx It's saver to split only on the `,` as this is the separating char. Imaging the string `foo, bar,foobar`, if the space was included this string would not be split properly.

Answer (score 3):

```
$ingredientsParts = explode(',', $row_rs_recipes['ingredients']);
    $li = '<ul>';
    foreach($ingredientsParts as $key=>$value){
         $li.=" <li>$value</li>";
    }
    $li.= '</ul>';

echo $li;
```

Answer (score 2):

this should be enough:

```
$ingredientsParts = explode(', ', $row_rs_recipes['ingredients']);

foreach ($ingredientsParts as $ingredient)
{ 
    echo "<li>$ingredient</li>";
}
```

or you can `explode` it by `','` and use `echo '<li>' . trim($ingredient) . '</li>';` to remove whitespace from beginning/end of that string

Answer (score 0):

The explode method already return an array, so you don't have to transform your variable $ingredientsParts into an array.

Just do:

```php
$ingredientsParts = explode(', ', $row_rs_recipes['ingredients']);
foreach ($ingredientsParts as $ingredient)
{ 
echo "<li>$ingredient</li>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!empty($recipe['ingredients'])) {
    echo '<ul><li>' . implode('</li><li>', explode(', ', $row_rs_recipes['ingredients'])) . '</li></ul>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
$ingredients = explode(',', $row_rs_recipes['ingredients']);

$list = '<ul>';

foreach ($ingredients as $ingredient) 
{
   $list .= '<li>' . $ingredient . '</li>';
}
$list .= '</ul>';

echo $list;
```